# Samsung Galaxy S2 I 9100 Ubuntu development

Tags: updates, android, samsung

several users of great phone S2 are asking when will ubuntu be stable to flash on our devices.So im asking is there someone that will soon fix all necessery issues to make ubuntu live on our phone.We are exppecting ubuntu like money jackpot.Thinking that it will be much smoother with great battery performance and optimisation.Please fix everything that is necessery to make os working.

Greetings from Serbia

Comment: I don't think your phone is officially supported as it does not meet the minimum specs for Ubuntu phone, the phone is popular so proberly you will find 3rd party roms online but you need to ask the creators of the roms.